# How to convey some expressions using the verb "beschweren"?

Tags: verb, verb-usage, reflexive

To me this word is actually an important one, because we like or dislike things, then when we dislike generally we complain. So I would like to use the verb *beschweren* correctly.
Which one of my examples below corresponds with the English sentence?

> The tourists complained that they had trouble following the guide.
>
> Die Touristen beschwert, dass sie sich schwer tun, den Reiseführer zu folgen.
> Die Touristen beschwert, dass sie im Anschluss an die Führung Probleme hatte.
> Die Touristen beschwert, dass sie Schwierigkeiten damit hatte, den Reiseführer zu folgen.

Comment: d) none of the above

Comment: The conjugation of beschweren in the plural is wrong.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Well, not wrong, it’s just the non-reflexive _beschweren_ that doesn’t fit here semantically.

Comment: Ja, es muss reflexiv sein.

Comment: I find this one better :-/  without using _beschweren_

"die Touristen sagten, dass sie sich den Reiseführer nicht folgen können hatten."

Comment: Well, do you want to mark that it is a complaint or not? Other things to look up: case governed by _folgen_, special word order in connection with _Ersatzinfinitiv_. And no idea where you got the _sich_ in that sentence from.

Comment: @chirlu,
Can we not convey complaint in german without using _beschweren_ ?and do we need to use always "sich beschweren"?

Comment: As for your second question: Yes, it *must be reflexive* if you mean "complain". Without, it would be some variety of "putting weight on something". -> "Briefbeschwerer" (paperweight).

Answer (score 3):

To use the verb *beschweren* correctly, you have to

1. use the right conjugation
2. add the reflexive you missed.

The answer is, or rather might be, the followoing:

> Die Touristen [right conjugation of *beschweren*] **sich** darüber, [*dass*-Nebensatz] ...

Answer (score -1):

The tourists complained that they had trouble following the guide.

```
"Die Touristen beschwert, dass sie sich schwer tun, den Reiseführer zu folgen."
```

This would probably be the correct answer, though the usage is a bit different. The correct sentence would be:

```
"Die Touristen beschweren sich (darüber), dass sie Schwierigkeiten hatte, dem Reiseführer zu folgen."
```

This one:

```
Die Touristen beschwert, dass sie im Anschluss an die Führung Probleme hatte.
```

Would be more: `"The Tourists complained, that they had problems after the tour."`

Comment: Is it possible complain with omitting actual verb e.g. "die Touristen sagten, dass sie sich den Reiseführer nicht folgen können hatten."

Comment: @Bergmann: Der Satz _die Touristen sagten, dass sie sich den Reiseführer nicht folgen können hatten_
ist grammatikalisch falsch.  Korrekt wäre:  _die Touristen sagten, dass sie  dem Reiseführer nicht folgen  hätten können_

Comment: @Karl but why in K II form?

Comment: @Bergmann, ja warum nur? Weil das eben die deutsche Grammatik so will!